# curl and python cookies are different

Tags: python, curl, cookies, python-requests

I have a set of curl commands that I'm trying to convert into python requests but I'm getting stuck on the cookies. In curl the instructions say to make a cookies file by

```
curl 'https://signon.jgi.doe.gov/signon/create' --data-urlencode 'login=USER_NAME' --data-urlencode 'password=USER_PASSWORD' -c cookies > /dev/null
```

Which gives me the following file

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.jgi.doe.gov    TRUE    /       FALSE   0       jgi_session     <REDACTED>
#HttpOnly_signon-old.jgi.doe.gov        FALSE   /       FALSE   0       _caliban_session        <REDACTED>
```

When I try the same thing in requests:

```
import requests
get_cookie = requests.post('https://signon.jgi.doe.gov/signon/create', data={'login':<USERNAME>, 'password': <PASSWORD>})
get_cookie.cookies
    <RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='_caliban_session', value='<REDACTED>', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='signon.jgi.doe.gov', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

The cookie that gets returned is the `_caliban_session`, which is commented out in the curl cookie file. The correct cookie, with the `jgi_session` in it doesn't appear to be returned. As a result my subsequent requests using the cookie are denied.

Why is it that the cookies are different between python and curl? and how can I get the python requests to match the curl cookie?

Comment: I think the reason why you did not get `jgi_session ` because you logged in unsuccessfully.

Comment: add --trace-ascii req.txt to watch your request, i got `'login=USER_NAME%27&'password=USER_PASSWORD%27` with curl. and `login=USER_NAME&password=USER_PASSWORD` with Python

Comment: thanks for the tip. How I can see a similar output though python as the --trace-ascii for curl?